# Triggering chosen:open event in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, jquery-chosen

I'm using [this](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) chosen directive for angularjs. It's working great. But what I want to do is trigger chosen:open event to programatically open the dropdown which can be found in [chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggerable-events). Have anyone achieved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could enhance this directive, so it listens to custom events, that you define per dropdown. This answer about [Extending Angular Directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005383/6192875) explains how this works.

```
module.directive('chosen', function(){
  return {
    restrict:"A",
    link: function($scope,$element,$attrs){
        var event = $attrs.openOn;
        $scope.$on(event,function(){
            $element.trigger("chosen:open");
        });
    }
  }
});

<button ng-click="show('event:a')">open</button>
<select chosen open-on="event:a">    

$scope.show = function(event) {
  $scope.$broadcast(event);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QbRAY/1/