# AngularJS - Bind Input to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my master `ng-controller`, I want to bind ALL inputs to a focus event and trigger a function. What I have tried (and failed) so far were:

```
// This makes sense since it is not a bind
$('input').focus(function(){});

// This should work, but doesn't!
$('input').bind('focus', function() {});
```

What are my options? How can I bind all `input` to a focus?

Comment: Read [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) it will help you in longer run

Comment: So you don't bind in Angular? What do you do then?

Comment: @Kousha Create a directive. The directive will be the one that handles this kind of thing. Also, see [ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)

Comment: @KemalFadillah, do you mean create a directive for `input` that is restricted to an element?

Comment: @Kousha I'd have a look at MajoB's answer, another question here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352564/angularjs-extend-input-directive), has a good couple of options for you on how to do this globally and/or for a more narrow scope in your application.

Comment: @KasperLewau, I went with a directive approach (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I ended up using a directive for this purpose:

```
app.directive('input', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.bind('focus', function(){});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add ngFocus directive to all input fields:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="controllerFunction()"></input>
```

Or read this answer how to do this globally for all inputs:
[AngularJS: extend input directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352564/angularjs-extend-input-directive)

Comment: No, this is too much to add an `ng-focus` to every input, specially that I would want to use that (maybe) for other functionalists. Worst comes worst, I'll just have a directive for input

Comment: @Kousha Then I think this is the proper way how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905165/1385075