# Angular 1.3.15 overwriting varaible in 3rd party directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have decided to use the [message service angular package](https://github.com/mateu-aguilo-bosch/message-center) in my current project. Within its directive there is a `var = templateString` which I would like to edit to a template of my choosing.

I would like to know how to edit this string without messing with the original code. I read a series of similar answers but closes I can find is to create a directive that completely overrides it. I just wish to edit the template string and leave in the existing code.

I'm using Angular 1.3.15

The directive

```js
MessageCenterModule.
  directive('mcMessages', ['$rootScope', 'messageCenterService', function ($rootScope, messageCenterService) {
    /*jshint multistr: true */
    var templateString = '\
    <div id="mc-messages-wrapper">\
      <div class="alert alert-{{ message.type }} {{ animation }}" ng-repeat="message in mcMessages">\
        <a class="close" ng-click="message.close();" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>\
        <span ng-switch on="message.html">\
        <span ng-switch-when="true">\
          <span ng-bind-html="message.message"></span>\
        </span>\
        <span ng-switch-default>\
          {{ message.message }}\
        </span>\
      </div>\
    </div>\
    ';
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: templateString,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Bind the messages from the service to the root scope.
        messageCenterService.flush();
        var changeReaction = function (event, to, from) {
          // Update 'unseen' messages to be marked as 'shown'.
          messageCenterService.markShown();
          // Remove the messages that have been shown.
          messageCenterService.removeShown();
          $rootScope.mcMessages = messageCenterService.mcMessages;
          messageCenterService.flush();
        };
        if (messageCenterService.offlistener === undefined) {
          messageCenterService.offlistener = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', changeReaction);
        }
        scope.animation = attrs.animation || 'fade in';
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Is it possible? What is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the directive using AngularJS decorators, like this:

```
MessageCenterModule
  .config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('mcMessagesDirective', function ($delegate) {

      var directive = $delegate[0];
      //assign a new value to the template
      directive.template = 'My template';
      return $delegate;

    });
  });
```

Comment: Sheesh, looks like someone beat me to it! :+1: to you sir.

Comment: Only by a few seconds, I +1d yours too since you provide links.

Comment: Throws an error. `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module favoriteEats due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MessageCenterModule due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mcMessagesProvider` Only when including the above code.

Comment: From my understanding this approach no longer works in Angular 1.3 +

Comment: Oops, made a mistake: It's $provide.decorator('mcMessagesDirective', it needs a suffix per https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L727. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm using a decorator to modify angular-ui's uiSelectDirective in a 1.3.15 project, the decorator is working for me. Try adding the 'Directive' suffix and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm so very sorry friend, you are going to have to override it.

**YOINK!** You're going to decorate it. Sounds a little posh but, hey. It works.

---

Whenever you use [$provide#decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator), you get the original instance as a local injectable by the name `$delegate`.

As such, you can *keep what you want*, and throw away what you don't.

First thing you're going to have to do is figure out *how* the original implementation makes use of what you want to modify, so as to not break the entire thing.

Luckily, the [templateString](https://github.com/mateu-aguilo-bosch/message-center/blob/master/message-center.js#L120) you are looking to modify is only used as the `directive.template`, so it should be a fairly easy decoration.

It would go something like this:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  /**
   * note the use of 'directivename' + 'Directive'.
   * Whenever you decorate a directive, you have to apply the 'Directive' suffix due to this: 
   * https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L727
   */
  $provide.decorator('mcMessagesDirective', function ($delegate) {
    /**
     * We're getting the item at the first index here, 
     * because the $delegate of a directive isn't quite an 'instance' - 
     * it's a collection of DDO's (directive definition objects) that
     * go by the same name. 
     *
     * Yes, the $compileProvider allows multiple directives with the same name. 
     * We're interested in the first one in this case.
     */
    var dir = $delegate[0]; 

    /**
     * Modify the template of the directive. 
     * You can either hardcode this, or:
     * - Decorate the directive so as to pass the template in. 
     * - Fetch a template with $http. 
     * - Inject a string from a service, constant, provider, you name it.
     */
    dir.template = 'your_own_custom_templateString';

    /**
     * Return the full collection of directives (or rather, 'the $delegate'). 
     */ 
    return $delegate; 
  });
});
```

And there you go, whenever you use `mcMessages` again, it'll make use of the hardcoded template you just gave it.

---

Moar links!

- [extend-input-directive@StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352564/angularjs-extend-input-directive/24905165#24905165) *(there's the right way, and the not-so right way)*
- [Experiment: Decorating Directives (by Jesus Rodriguez)](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)