# Best way to extend third party libraries in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the angular bootstrap ui third party library as a dependency inside my angular app.  I was just wondering what is the best way to add functionality to directives and controllers inside this library?

I understand that I can just edit the directives/controllers inside ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js, but if I were to re pull the dependencies on a build server, it would wipe away my changes.  If I were to update the library version it would also wipe away my changes.  I'm looking for a clean way to extend functionality.

For example, if I want to do something like extend the datepicker directive to accept a customMethod or customData then use these within the linking function.  What is the best way to do this?

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" custom-method="myCustomMethod()" 
    custom-attribute="myCustomAttribute" min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending Angular Directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005122/extending-angular-directive)

Comment: Thanks patrick, I had tried the two directives with the same name but was not able to achieve adding custom methods or attributes to the scope.  I was able to extend the linking function though.

Comment: There were other answers in there, one being the same as the answer provided here, hence why i have marked it as duplicate.

Comment: It's very similar, I had tried the other answers but was unable to get the linking function working properly.  I wasn't able to figure out how to extend the old linking function without completely overwriting it.  The answer provided by @dustyrockpyle gave me the last step.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, if this answer was better than the other than its fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to decorate the directive. Decoration looks something like:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).
    config(function($provide){
        // Inject provide into the config of your app
        $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate){

            // the directive is the first element of $delegate
            var datepicker = $delegate[0];

            // Add whatever you want to the scope:
            angular.extend(datepicker.scope, {
                customAttribute: '@',
                customMethod: '@'
            });

            // Might want to grab a reference to the old link incase
            // you want to use the default behavior.
            var oldLink = datepicker.link;

            datepicker.link = function(scope, element, attrs){
                // here you can write your new link function
                oldLink(scope, element, attrs);
            };

            return $delegate; 
        });
    });
```