# Extending a 3rd-party Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I've looked at the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005122/extending-angular-directive) and [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#extending-directives) for extending a 3rd-party Angular directive. What I really need to do though is extend a 3rd-party Angular controller.

I'm using the [Smart Table](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table) library in my application and its suggestion for implementing [list row selection with checkboxes](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/413). My application however, requires two types of selections:

1. Checkbox selection, where checkboxes can be used to select a single or multiple rows (already covered with the csSelectAll directive in the link above)
2. Row highlighting, where only a single row can be highlighted

It would be easy for me to write a highlight function for the `stTableController` based on the [select method](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stTable.js#L133). But I would like to be able to do this without forking Smart Table myself.

I tried the solution for [extending controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19670187), but it appears to assume that the parent and child controller live in the same module. When I try the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('smarterTableController', function(<required deps>) {
     $controller('smartTableController', {$scope: $scope}));
     //initialization stuff left out...
     this.highlight = function(row) {
       var rows = copyRefs(displayGetter($scope));
       var index = rows.indexOf(row);
       if (index !== -1) {
         row.isHighlighted = row.isHighlighted !== true;
         if (lastHighlighted) {
           lastHighlighted.isHighlighted = false;
         }
        lastHighlighted = row.isHighlighted === true ? row : undefined;
      }
    };
  });
  //corresponding extension of the stTable directive to use the smarterTableController
```

This solution doesn't appear to work though. When I call the parent controller's function using `$controller`, I get the error:

`Argument 'smartTableController' is not a function, got undefined`

Here are my two questions:

1. Should I be able to extend a 3rd-party controller in this way?
2. If not, is forking the project and adding this extra bit of functionality my only other option?

Comment: For your second question, it is kind to do a pull request on the main branch after your changes ;-)

Comment: Of course, I would definitely open an issue with the original project asking them if they are interested in my changes and contribute if they want them. I don't want to maintain my own fork for this one thing after all :-). But I don't know how common needing to select *and* highlight is, so I didn't want to be presumptuous by creating a pull request straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should create a custom directive, using the `require` parameter.

Have a look at the doc here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("smarterTable", function(){
    return {
        require:"smartTable",
        link: function(arg1, arg2, arg3, smartTableController){
             // Put your logic here
        }
    }


});
```

And in your view, you will have to add :

```
<smart-table smarter-table=""></smart-table>
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Right now I've made my own fork because it was quicker. Your solution appears nicer, but I don't yet understand how it works and probably won't understand till I actually implement it myself.

Comment: When you create a directive, the argument  `require` looks for a controller on the same element. It then passes the controller object (or scope) to your link function (which is, in the directive lifecycle executer after the controller).